# C# reader is closed while reading?

Tags: c#, class, while-loop, listbox, sqldatareader

I am running a C# windows application, and I get an error message when trying to use a datareader. The error message is:

> "Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed."

I used stop point and saw that the code works fine until it enters the "while" loop. Once inside, it gives the error message.

I have tried to do it without closing the previous reader, but then the message changed to something like "there is already an open reader" or some such.

Here's the code:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionString);
SqlCommand select_cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usrRealname, usrIsowner FROM tblUSERS WHERE usrNum = " + UserID, conn);
SqlCommand select_orders = new SqlCommand("SELECT orderNum, orderBy, orderShipadrs, orderDate, orderTotal FROM tblOrders WHERE orderDeliveryDate is NULL AND fkorderTakenbyusrnum = " + UserID, conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = select_cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
CurrentUser User = new CurrentUser(Convert.ToString(dr[0]), UserID, Convert.ToBoolean(dr[1]));
DetailsLabel.Text = String.Format("Welcome {0}, ID number {1}. {2}", User.getname, UserID, User.getOwner);
dr.Close();
SqlDataReader orders = select_orders.ExecuteReader();
while (orders.Read())
{
UnfulfilledOrders CurrentOrder = new UnfulfilledOrders(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToString(dr[1]), Convert.ToString(dr[2]), Convert.ToString(dr[3]), Convert.ToInt32(dr[4]));
OrderList.Items.Add(CurrentOrder);
}
```

What I'd trying to do is add class (UnfulfilledOrders) type objects to a listbox (OrderList).

The thing that baffles me is that I used such a while loop in a previous form in the same app, and it worked fine there.
I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I tried twiking the code, adding or removing certain parts, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Clearly you are reading from closed reader `dr.Close(); .... dr[0]`,...  what do you expect code to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in your while loop you're using dr[0] instead of orders[0].  This is trying to get the value from the SqlDataReader dr.

A good way to avoid mix-ups like this would be to create the data reader in a using block.

```
using (var dr = select_cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   //your code here
   dr.Close();
}
```

then

```
using (var orders = select_orders.ExecuteReader())
{
  // your code here
  orders.Close();
}
```

This would prevent you from accidently referencing the wrong reader because VS would give you an error saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: Wooooooooooooow that was so stupid of me...
I'm not used to dealing with more than one datareader at a time. Usually we just use the default "dr" that our teacher gave us to work with.

Anyway, that indeed solved the problem. Will mark as answer.

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
dr.Close();  //<-- dr closed
SqlDataReader orders = select_orders.ExecuteReader(); // <-- Reader is "orders" here
while (orders.Read())
{
UnfulfilledOrders CurrentOrder = new UnfulfilledOrders(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToString(dr[1]),     Convert.ToString(dr[2]), Convert.ToString(dr[3]), Convert.ToInt32(dr[4]));
OrderList.Items.Add(CurrentOrder);
}
```

dr was closed previously, do you mean "orders" instead of "dr"?